# How to allow IIS to use local database from ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm going to be demoing a ASP.NET MVC website on a local network. This application has a connection to a database:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-EBC-20141127093222.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-EBC-20141127093222;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**I would like if this database can be used by both IIS and whenever I run my application locally.** I've made a site on IIS - it is running .NET v4. My project lives in `c:\inetpub\www\ebc`. I can publish the website but recieve this error upon viewing the page:

---

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Unexpected error occurred inside a LocalDB instance API method call. See the Windows Application event log for error details."

I know I need to allow remote connections to the sql server through microsoft sql server manager? Is there a way to do it elsewhere?

Answer (score 11):

The best solution is to use SQL Expression but if you don't want there are few steps that you have to do to make your mvc application work with localdb

1. Open Visual studio command prompt as administrator
2. execute `sqllocaldb share v11.0 IIS_DB` (then the database will be shared and IIS can access it)
3. Change the site connection string to point to the shared instance of DB: `Data Source=(LocalDb)\.\IIS_DB` then publish again

Note that in this point you may receive an access deny error and there is how to fix it

1. Go to visual studio => databaseexplorer => add connection
2. For the server name enter `(LocalDb)\.\IIS_DB` then right click on the connection and choose new query and execute this command

   ```
   create login [IIS APPPool\DefaultAPPPool] from windows;
   exec sp_addsrvrolemember N'IIS APPPool\DefaultAPPPool, sysadmin
   ```

Answer (score 3):

When there are multiple version of SQL Server localDB installed in a machine, this error is very common.

Try to use `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`, as a common server name to connect to the LocalDB automatic instance, instead of "v11.0" or "v12.0".

The above automatic localdb instance, have a default name across all the version and avoid conflict between name & version.

**Important**: When updating the localdb to new version, remember the database created with an older version does not work with the newer.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like this:

Start by using Developer PowerShell or Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio as Administrator and confirm that you only have one instance of LocalDb.

Type `sqllocaldb info` to see your LocalDb instances.

[image]

I then followed this article and had Application Pool Identity set to my currently logged in user, credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38294458/3850405

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlexpress/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile

In there I found that it is not enough to have `Load User Profile` set to true for your Application Pool, you also need to set `setProfileEnvironment` to true in `applicationHost.config` normally located at `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`. With this configuration it worked:

[image]

Original answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62810876/3850405

Answer (score 1):

See this post:
These two posts on Using LocalDB with Full IIS should give you more information. Especially the second part seems relevant, but the first one contains some context as well.

1. [Part 1: User Profile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx)
2. [Part 2: Instance Ownership](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership.aspx)

Credit: [IIS connecting to LocalDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308654/iis-connecting-to-localdb)

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Notepad app as Administrator and navigate to folder C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config. Open file applicationHost.config, search for "setProfileEnvironment" and set its value to "true". Save and exit Notepad.
2. Run Command Prompt app as Administrator and execute the following command,
   SQLLOCALDB SHARE MSSQLLocalDB IIS_MSSQLLocalDB
3. Change "Data Source" value in the connection string to (localDb).\IIS_MSSQLLocalDB.
4. On the LocalDB execute the following sql command,

- CREATE LOGIN [IIS APPPool{app pool name}] FROM WINDOWS;
- EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember N'IIS APPPool{app pool name}', SYSADMIN

CREDIT: @AnotherGeek on this very thread. Thank you.