# Can't connect to shared local database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I used the following windows command to share my local database : -

```
sqlLocalDB share v11.0 IIS_DB
```

When trying to connect to the database via the database explorer in Visual Studio 2012 using the shared name I get the following error: -

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow IIS to use local database from ASP.NET MVC project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324951/how-to-allow-iis-to-use-local-database-from-asp-net-mvc-project)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I've already done the steps in that link but I'm still having a problem

Comment: I have discussed about this error here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37482209/1666800

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I connect to my local SQL Server database instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481786/why-cant-i-connect-to-my-local-sql-server-database-instance)